# Scale a plane in any of x or z axis using random function in time intervals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am quite new to Unity3D, and I expect some help here!

I am working out on a project where I have created a 3D Object>Plane. What I want is the plane should extrude or scale towards a specific axis (x or z) provided randomly using InvokeRepeating function.

Reference Image :
[image: The Line is plane]

The problem I am facing is how can i turn the plane on an axis and scale in into that direction.

Comment: Have you thought about using normal vectors?
Plan provides normal vectors by default.

Comment: I am quite new to unity3D. Let me search for it. Also if you can share some reference it would be helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Trying to figure out. Hope it helps!

Comment: so you say actually you want to spawn multiple instance of your plane object? Or is this supposed to happen in a single mesh instance (=> would require procedural mesh in that case)? And can this really be random? ;) What if the line crosses somewhere after completing a circle?